# i have set display: flex and flex-wrap for a container however its items are not wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Code:

```css
 

    body {
      font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      min-height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .header {
      height: 72px;
      background: darkmagenta;
      color: white;
      font-size: 32px;
      font-weight: 900;
      padding-left: 16px;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
    }
    
    .footer {
      height: 72px;
      background: #eee;
      color: darkmagenta;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    
    .sidebar {
      width: 300px;
      background: royalblue;
      flex-shrink: 0;
      padding: 16px;
    }
    
    ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    li {
      margin-bottom: 16px;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    
    .card {
      border: 1px solid #eee;
      box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
      border-radius: 4px;
      margin: 16px;
      padding: 16px;
    }
    
    .container {
      padding: 32px;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    
    .body {
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>The Holy Grail</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="header">
        MY AWESOME WEBSITE
      </div>
      <div class="body">
        <div class="sidebar">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="google.com">⭐ - link one</a></li>
            <li><a href="google.com">‍♂️ - link two</a></li>
            <li><a href="google.com">️ - link three</a></li>
            <li><a href="google.com"> - link four</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, eveniet? Dolorem dignissimos maiores non delectus possimus dolor nulla repudiandae vitae provident quae, obcaecati ipsam unde impedit corrupti veritatis minima porro?</div>
          <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi quaerat qui iure ipsam maiores velit tempora, deleniti nesciunt fuga suscipit alias vero rem, corporis officia totam saepe excepturi odit ea.</div>
          <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia esse autem?</div>
          <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde earum minima laboriosam eos!</div>
          <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia esse autem?</div>
          <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde earum minima laboriosam eos!</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        The Odin Project ❤️
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here I added the display: flex; and flex-wrap: wrap; for the class container, with class card as flex items. However the cards are not wrapping. I checked the parent body and it has `display: flex;` set so I don't know where I went wrong.

[This is the output I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6J7oX.jpg)

[This is the desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Qts.png)

Comment: Your cards are too wide, you need to limit their width.

Comment: By defining some width to them.

Comment: To add more context to the comments, by default, block elements will take up 100 percent of the width of their parent container - that's why you need to define a width (in your case percentage) for the `.card` elements.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Be ensure your flex item have maximum width . than the main container will be wrapping.

```css
.card {

  max-width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a fixed-width to your `cards`. Without defining a width, flex-box is going to try to determine the width for them, based on the screen size. If you set a fixed-width the cards will keep that width upon resizing the browser, which then your `flex-wrap: wrap;` on your container will kick in and wrap them when there is not enough space. I added `width: 350px;` to your `card` See the changes below.

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header {
  height: 72px;
  background: darkmagenta;
  color: white;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding-left: 16px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer {
  height: 72px;
  background: #eee;
  color: darkmagenta;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 300px;
  background: royalblue;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding: 16px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.card {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 16px rgba(0,0,0,.06);
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
  width: 350px;
  min-width: 150px;
}

.container {
  padding: 32px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>The Holy Grail</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    MY AWESOME WEBSITE
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="google.com">⭐ - link one</a></li>
        <li><a href="google.com">‍♂️ - link two</a></li>
        <li><a href="google.com">️ - link three</a></li>
        <li><a href="google.com"> - link four</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, eveniet? Dolorem dignissimos maiores non delectus possimus dolor nulla repudiandae vitae provident quae, obcaecati ipsam unde impedit corrupti veritatis minima porro?</div>
      <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi quaerat qui iure ipsam maiores velit tempora, deleniti nesciunt fuga suscipit alias vero rem, corporis officia totam saepe excepturi odit ea.</div>
      <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia esse autem?</div>
      <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde earum minima laboriosam eos!</div>
      <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Nobis illo ex quas, commodi eligendi aliquam ut, dolor, atque aliquid iure nulla. Laudantium optio accusantium quaerat fugiat, natus officia esse autem?</div>
      <div class="card">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus nihil impedit eius amet adipisci dolorum vel nostrum sit excepturi corporis tenetur cum, dolore incidunt blanditiis. Unde earum minima laboriosam eos!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    The Odin Project ❤️
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you use a fixed width here? Why not a percentage or responsive width? Using a fixed width will create overflow issues.

Comment: @disinfor IMO fixed-width keeps the integrity of the card width when resizing. If I used `%`'s it would go based on screen width making the cards insanely skinny on a mobile device. I suppose using `25vw` would be fine, but still would eventually be skinny on mobile screens.

Comment: Fixed width is awful for responsive websites. In this case, fixed width is not a good solution. And to your comment, setting a fixed width would make the cards overflow the y axis and create a horizontal scroll.

Comment: @disinfor I'll respectfully disagree. I agree fixed widths are mostly bad especially for responsive websites, but in this case, it's not because it's a child element `card` and has a flex-box associated with it that auto wraps each card. Cards were overflowing x-axis, which is now corrected.

Comment: I questioned the fact you used fixed-width. It's not my fault OP accepted a different answer. I didn't down vote your answer - which would be more of a dispute than a simple comment.

Comment: It's all good. I agree - your answer is better, the other answer is essentially a more unclear version of yours - that was posted a couple hours after. SO is funny place sometimes.